# How pass current user name to endpoints - I want recognize user and assign rights?

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I pass current user credential to endpoints function.

Let assume such scenario:

1. User if forced to login to google app engine with use Google Account.
2. I want to assign specific rights to specific user at endpoints.

Can you show some example how to do it?

I study doucmentation but still not found solution.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/

Comment: how about https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/

Comment: Yes it can work. What if I want authenticate dynamic number of applications?